# mix ecto.create bcrypt_elyxir and nmake error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, nmake

I have a problem with Phoenix when ordering mix ecto.create.

I look for a solution in but I can not find anything ..

If you have an idea, I thank you for it.

[image: Terminal Error]

Comment: Have you looked into installing `nmake`?

Comment: I reinstalled nmake, I now have the following error:

(ErlangError) Erlang error: :eacces
    erlang.erl:2118: :erlang.open_port({:spawn_executable, 'c:/Users/Victor/AppData/Roaming/npm/nmake.cmd'}, [{:env, []}, {:cd, "d:/Programme/Nouveau dossier/Sentinel/deps/bcrypt_elixir"}, :stderr_to_stdout, :use_stdio, :exit_status, :binary, :hide, {:args, ["/F", "Makefile.win"]}])

Comment: `eacces` means you do not have permission to execute that command.

Comment: Do you have an idea to unlock this ?